# Forward fill in pandas dataframe based on specific label in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to forward feel the data within specific label (where label defined in other column:

```
LABEL | Col1 | ffil_col |
-------------------------
    1 |  N   | female   |
    1 |  M   |          |
    2 |  A   |          |
    2 |  N   | male     |
    2 |  M   |          |
```

need to be this:

```
LABEL | Col1 | ffil_col |
-------------------------
    1 |  N   | female   |
    1 |  M   | female   |
    2 |  A   |          |
    2 |  N   | male     |
    2 |  M   | male     |
```

the only Idea I have so far is to use `groupby` by label, then `ffill` each group,
and then concat everything back. Is there any alternative and more clear solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on the groupby, which retains the same length as the original dataframe.

```
df['ffil_col'] = df.groupby('LABEL').ffil_col.transform(lambda group: group.ffill())

>>> df
   LABEL Col1 ffil_col
0      1    N   female
1      1    M   female
2      2    A      NaN
3      2    N     male
4      2    M     male
```